# trying to install something on an ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running this line in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

and here's the output I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bcrelay
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcrelay pptpd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 96.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 446 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main bcrelay amd64 1.3.4-3ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main pptpd amd64 1.3.4-3ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptpd/bcrelay_1.3.4-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptpd/pptpd_1.3.4-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

what am i doing wrong? is this a known issue?

Comment: "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run `apt-get update` ..."

Comment: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal), which is no longer supported.  You need to upgrade to the latest Long Term Support (LTS) version, 12.04, via 11.10, as explained here:

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/10/28/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-end-of-life-reached-on-october-28-2012/

Answer (score 0):

That repository is not responding to your update requests.

I believe adding other repositories by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` should solve your problem. Look at this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) for more details.